# C# How to get rid of "\" from JSON?

Tags: c#, json

I have following C# code which generates output like this:

```
    Task<OnlineResponse> task = client.Execute(query);
    OnlineResponse response = task.Result;
    Result result = response.Results[0];

    dynamic resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Data);
        
    var x = Regex.Replace(resultJson.ToString(), @"[\[\]']+", "");

    return x;
```

This is output:

```
"{\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264378-1756289-919567-- 
accrual\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}},
{\"GLDETAIL\":{\"RECORDNO\":\"264378-1756290-919568--   
accrual\",\"BATCH_DATE\":\"02/01/2022\"}}"
```

I am trying to get rid of all backslashes.

I applied "Regex.Replace", but it would not work.

This is expected output:

```
"{"GLDETAIL":{"RECORDNO":"264378-1756289-919567-- 
accrual","BATCH_DATE":"02/01/2022"}},
{"GLDETAIL":{"RECORDNO":"264378-1756290-919568--   
accrual","BATCH_DATE":"02/01/2022"}}"
```

Comment: The backslash is used to escape the quotes in JSON string.

Comment: Yes, Yong is right, if you return this json string to API response or you write on a file you won't see that `\\`, I think you can see in the consol log only

Comment: Post more context; you're probably doing the wrong thing regards your serializing - i.e. if you serialize yourself and then return the serialized string, .net will serialize it again and escape the ". Ideally You just make an object and return it, it's .net's propblen to serialize it, not yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you serialized json string twice. just return the result.Data as it is. its already a json string. if you remove backslashes you wont be able deserilze the object.